# how to create login form using sqlite in iphone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, sqlite

i have created register page for login view  i need to execute the query for successful login here is my code

Register.h

```
@interface register1 : UIViewController{
    sqlite3 *logindb;

    NSString *databasePath;

}
-(IBAction)submit:(id)sender;
@property(retain, nonatomic)IBOutlet UITextField *username;
@property(retain, nonatomic)IBOutlet UITextField *password;
@property(retain, nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel *status;
```

register.m

```
@synthesize username,password,status;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    // Get the documents directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    // Build the path to the database file
    databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"login.db"]];
    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO)
    {
        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &logindb) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            char *errMsg;
            const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOGIN(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, USERNAME TEXT, PASSWORD TEXT)";


            if (sqlite3_exec(logindb, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                NSLog(@"Failed to create table") ;            }

            sqlite3_close(logindb);

        } else {
            NSLog( @"Failed to open/create database");
        }
    }

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(IBAction)submit:(id)sender{
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &logindb) == SQLITE_OK)
{
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO LOGIN (username, password) VALUES (\"%@\",\"%@\" )", username.text, password.text];

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(logindb, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            status.text = @"Registartion Done";
            username.text = @"";
            password.text = @"";

        } else {
            status.text = @"Failed to Register";
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(logindb);
    }


}
```

login.h

```
    IBOutlet UITextField *username;
    IBOutlet UITextField *password;

    -(IBAction)submit:(id)sender;
```

login.m

```
    -(IBAction)submit:(id)sender{
        if([username.text isEqualToString:@""] || [password.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
            UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Here comes a block." message:@"You missed something, please check your details and try again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
    }
        else{
            NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from login where username=\"%@\" and password=\"%@\"",username.text,password.text];
            NSLog(@"%@",query);
             }
```

i can able to make register successfully but not able to success login to execute queries

Comment: Are you able to get values form sqlite.update the full code of submit method.

Comment: I think you should make sure you have correctly insert registration info into sqlite, and then make sure you have get values from sqlite

Comment: @user3251949 then where you got stuck.

Comment: want success login and jumps next view controller

Comment: update submit method full code. in login.m

Comment: that is my full code in login.m

Comment: You have to perform full operation with database to select data from DB.